# mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727'

Tags: .net-4.0, vbscript, .net-3.5, mixed-mode

I am trying to make a COM for my old project. The COM is built successfully, but when I tried to use the COM to call some functions, this error comes out:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

The old project have some parts in .NET 4.0, and some parts in .NET 3.5. Though I tried to make all parts in .NET 4.0, some third party DLLs I used cannot be rebuilt to higher framework.

I have searched this problem, and all people told me to add a app.config or web.config to the application that:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku='.NETFramework,Version=v4.0' />
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
```

This will work when form or server calling. But my COM may be called by vbs like:

```
Dim obj
Set obj = CreateObject("ClassLib.Class1")
msgbox obj.add(3,5)
```

In this case, I can't add that config file to the vb file. Is there any solution fot this?

Comment: Don't you think people meant that you should add this app.config to your old project and rebuild with that?

Comment: Technically you can give the VBScript interpreter that .config file as well.  It doesn't scale very well.  The only true fix is to get this mixed-mode assembly built to target 4.0 or to go back to 3.5